# How add a single menu item left to the toolbar in android?

Tags: android, toolbar, menuitem, android-toolbar, android-actionbaractivity

I simply want a back button in left side of toolbar.But when i added with following code ,appear in right side of toolbar.how can i change to it to left side?

my code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context="com.me.myapp.activities.Timer">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:title="Back Button"
        android:icon="@mipmap/back_icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Don't add another icon if you're trying to get the back button. Use  `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need `Back` icon on top left side of ToolBar then just configure `Toolbar`.

```
mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
mToolBar.setTitle("Toolbar");
mToolBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_shadow);
setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
```

As `ToolBar` menu items are totally depend on either your device is on RTL(Right-To-Left) support or not which are mainly used for `menu items` and not for `back key`.

Moreover you can handle that back icon with

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep a back button and override its clicklistener to do some different work? like open a dialog?